# Azure ARM Template: Is there a way expand a two layer nest-array into one layer?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I have a parameter as below, it's an array with a nested inner array

```json
"parameters": {
  "input": {
    "type": "array",
    "defaultValue": [
      {
        "clusterName": "clusterNameA",
        "databaseName": "databaseNameA",
        "innerArray": {
          "value": [
            {
              "principalId": "id1",
              "role": "Viewer"
            },
            {
              "principalId": "id2",
              "role": "Ingestor"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "clusterName": "clusterNameB",
        "databaseName": "databaseNameB",
        "innerArray": {
          "value": [
            {
              "principalId": "id3",
              "role": "Viewer"
            },
            {
              "principalId": "id4",
              "role": "Ingestor"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create an array variable by expanding the innerArrays so it looks like below? The context behind this is ARM seems doesn't support nest-copy directly so I tried to workaround it by expanding.

```json
[
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameA",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameA",
    "principalId": "id1",
    "role": "Viewer"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameA",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameA",
    "principalId": "id2",
    "role": "Ingestor"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameB",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameB",
    "principalId": "id3",
    "role": "Viewer"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameB",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameB",
    "principalId": "id4",
    "role": "Ingestor"
  }
]
```

I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Cause you've tagged this question with `azure-bicep`, I feel like you could use these functions to help you solve your problem:

- [map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-lambda#map):

> Applies a custom mapping function to each element of an array.

- [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#flatten):

> Takes an array of arrays, and returns an array of subarray elements, in the original order. Subarrays are only flattened once, not recursively.

This worked for me:

```bicep
// main.bicep
param input array

output flatten array = flatten(map(input, cluster => map(cluster.innerArray.value, inner => {
  clusterName: cluster.clusterName
  databaseName: cluster.databaseName
  principalId: inner.principalId
  role: inner.role
})))
```

The equivalent ARM (`az bicep build --file main.bicep`) looks like that :

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "input": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "flatten": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[flatten(map(parameters('input'), lambda('cluster', map(lambdaVariables('cluster').innerArray.value, lambda('inner', createObject('clusterName', lambdaVariables('cluster').clusterName, 'databaseName', lambdaVariables('cluster').databaseName, 'principalId', lambdaVariables('inner').principalId, 'role', lambdaVariables('inner').role))))))]"
    }
  }
}
```

and give this result:

```json
[
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameA",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameA",
    "principalId": "id1",
    "role": "Viewer"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameA",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameA",
    "principalId": "id2",
    "role": "Ingestor"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameB",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameB",
    "principalId": "id3",
    "role": "Viewer"
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "clusterNameB",
    "databaseName": "databaseNameB",
    "principalId": "id4",
    "role": "Ingestor"
  }
]
```